# GLSL uniform behaviour

Tags: java, opengl, glsl, lwjgl

So in order to start my initiation with shaders, I decided to create a simple
program where a rendered texture (Loaded with Slick) gets progressively darker with a key press. Everything works as intended but I don't seem to be able to understand uniforms correctly and how the interact with the shaders. 
This is my simple **vertex** shader:

```
varying vec2 vTexCoord;

void main()
{
    vTexCoord = gl_MultiTexCoord0.xy;
    gl_Position = ftransform();
}
```

And the **fragment** shader:

```
uniform sampler2D myTexture;
uniform vec3 darknessParam;
varying vec2 vTexCoord;

void main()
{
    gl_FragColor = texture2D(myTexture, vTexCoord).rgba *  vec4(darknessParam, 1);
}
```

So the program executes as intended, but while I set normally the uniform `darknessParam`, I do not set the uniform `sampler2D`or refer to it at all in the main java-lwjgl program. So how does the fragment shader use the uniform `sampler2D` without me setting it anywhere? 
Thanks in advance and I apologise for the long post.
Have a nice day!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Use sampler without passing through value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27941496/use-sampler-without-passing-through-value)

Comment: it is possible duplicate you are right. I voted it to close as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First `sampler2D` is a type not a uniform, so I interpret the questions a the following:

I did not set `myTexture` to any value, why does it still work?

To access a texture in a shader with a sampler object the number of the texture unit has to be passed to the uniform. See for example here: https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Sampler_%28GLSL%29#Binding_textures_to_samplers

Assuming now, that you are using texture unit 0 the uniform does not need to be set, because all uniforms are 0 initialized.

From https://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man31/html/glLinkProgram.xhtml

> As a result of a successful link operation, all active user-defined
>   uniform variables belonging to program will be initialized to 0,...